# ASP.NET routing on IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-routing

I have created a basic site using [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) routing according to Mike Ormond's example "Using ASP.NET routing Independent of MVC". This works fine on my local machine running the built-in web server.

However, when I deploy it to my server ([Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003), [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 6, ASP.NET 3.5 SP1) it just shows a 404 error.

I have read somewhere that I am meant to set up wildcard routing. How can I do this?

What other configuration changes needs to be done to make it work on my server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will find some good information on Steve Sanderson’s blog post "[Deploying ASP.NET MVC to IIS 6](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/)."

Answer (score 18):

On the server, open IIS:

1. Right-click on the site/virtual directory, select properties
2. Goto the Home Directory/Virtual Directory tab, click Configuration (near the bottom)
3. Near the bottom again, click the insert button
4. Enter **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll**
5. Alternate: Enter **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll** for ASP.NET 4.0
6. **Uncheck** the "Verify that file exists" button, click Okay and close all the dialogues

Comment: For info, a user has reported (now deleted) that the "insert" button is missing in his case. That isn't your fault, of course!

Comment: Any reason for using the v2 version of the dll and not the v4?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the "official" discussion of wildcard mappings on [TechNet here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true) but I like Phil Haack's walkthrough that you can [find here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx). Don't worry about the fact that it's a discussion of setting up [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework), just look for the section titled "IIS6 Extension-less URLs" - that set up applies to both MVC and using routing with a classic [web form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_%28web%29) application.

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS 6 64 bit, make sure that the path under 4.) points to 
**C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll**

Answer (score 0):

Url rewriting can help you to solve the problem. I've implemented solution allowing to deploy MVC application at any IIS version even when virtual hosting is used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx