# .Net 4 Routing not working properly on IIS6 (Stylesheet/Image Intercept)

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, routes, iis-6

I have a mobile website, intercepting the stylesheet/images and setting sizes relative to the device. I have been testing it on IIS7 and works fine.

The live site is IIS6 (lil surprise)...

Normal routing for *friendly urls* works fine, but the stylesheet/images intercept is not doing anything.

Here is a snippet of my global.asax routing section :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
                routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

                routes.MapPageRoute("ImageResizerS", "images/{Sub}/{Path}", "~/Site_Handlers/ImageResize.ashx");
                routes.MapPageRoute("ImageResizer", "images/{Path}", "~/Site_Handlers/ImageResize.ashx");

                routes.MapPageRoute("StyleSheetIntercept", "Styles/{Path}", "~/Site_Handlers/InterceptStyleSheet.ashx");

                routes.MapPageRoute("Landing page", "", "~/Site_Files/LandingPage.aspx");
    }
```

**What seems to be the problem?**

*What I have noticed :*

When I set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` to **`false`**. It creates the same behavior on IIS7 & IIS6...no intercept.

Comment: Is the site on IIS 6 a virtual directory or full web site?

Comment: On it's own domain...it's a full website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On the server, open IIS:**

1. Right-click on the site/virtual directory, select properties
2. Goto the Home Directory/Virtual Directory tab, click Configuration (near the bottom)
3. Near the bottom again, click the insert button
4. Enter **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll** - *Used v4 in this case.*
5. **Uncheck** the "Verify that file exists" button, click Okay and close all the dialogues

**REFERENCE:** [ASP.NET routing on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811871/asp-net-routing-on-iis-6)

Answer (score 1):

In IIS6, you need to enable wildcard mapping to ensure that the correct handler picks up the request (in this case ASP.Net), otherwise it will just be served like a static web page.  See [Microsoft web site](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true) for a how to.

The executable path in step 4 will vary depending on your .Net version, but the easiest way is to copy the value from one of the other mapping that .Net already handles (.aspx, .ashx, etc.)